# Voice Memo transfer tools from iOS 15 to macOS (to Windows optional) even with the current iOS 15 "bug"?

Tags: osx, ios, macos, voice-recording, data-transfer

I've been using PhoneView for over several years to transfer Voice Memos from iOS to macOS. A year or so ago it started to have trouble and seemed to not work reliably and now it's not working at all.

Are there any other similar programs that allow the transfer of files from an iOS device like PhoneView - particularly Voice Memos - independently from iTunes / Music.app?

I am most particularly interested in open source options that are still supported / maintained.

It does appear as though there is a bug or some kind of issue as noted by @GDP2 in the comments for iOS15. It seems, though, that doing a transfer via the filesystem access may still be attainable... Trying to research this myself as well for options.

Comment: Apparently this is an issue across the board for iOS 15. See the following links for examples of others who are also struggling with this as of of the latest update: https://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-backup-iphone-voice-memos/, https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253241919, https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253316749